# double.parse convert two zero decimal to one decimal

Tags: c#

I have a string 10.00 and I want to convert it to double 10.00.

I use :

```
string str = "10.00";
double db = double.Parse(str);
```

the result I get is 10.0 and not 10.00.

Comment: Ok, I think it is still acceptable.

Comment: Raymond Chen, dropping truth bombs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A double isn't a string.  If you want to display the double as a string, you can format it to have two decimal points.

For example:

```
string str = "10.00";
double db = double.Parse(str);
String.Format("{0:0.00}", db); // will show 10.00
```

Answer (score 5):

The `Parse` and `TryParse` on the numeric respect local culture settings; you can change this by specifying a `CultureInfo` object. For instance, parsing `2.999` into a double gives `2999` in Germany:

```
Console.WriteLine (double.Parse ("2.999"));   // 2999 (In Germany)
```

This is because in Germany, the period indicates a thousands separator rather than a decimal point. Specifying invariant culture fixes this:

```
double x = double.Parse ("2.999", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The same when calling `ToString()`:

```
string x = 2.9999.ToString (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Question isn't really clear, but if you are referring to changing the double back to string with 2 decimal place precision, you can use:

```
string str = "10.00"
double db = double.parse(str);
string convertedBack = db.ToString("0.00");
```